# What are exercise a kidney patient can do?

Tags: exercise, workout

I want to know what exercises a kidney patient can do other than jogging?

Comment: Is jogging really OK for kidney patients?

In Russia all kidney patients I've heard of were specifically forbidden from jogging by their doctors.  Having a kidney disease also exempts men from compulsory service in the Russian army.

I guess the reasoning behind it is that when you jog you slowly dehydrate your organism and leave it in dehydrated state for longer periods, which increases the concentration of urine, which then increases the probability of accumulation of minerals in bladder/kidneys («kidney stones») (but I'm not sure since I'm not a doctor).

Comment: @MischaArefiev Actually doc have suggested me to jog daily. So i m following that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick search to see what was recommended.  While I've collected a few recommendations, I don't have the reasoning for them.  The most directly useful link was [this one](http://ihatedialysis.com/forum/index.php?topic=18814.0) summarized below:

- Focus on continuous activity like swimming, jogging, aerobic exercise where you move large muscle groups continuously
- Light strength training is OK (lower weights higher reps)
- Exercise three non-consecutive days a week
- Discontinue exercise if you are dehydrated, very tired, have shortness of breath, have a fever, change in dialysis schedule.

[Kidney.org had a brochure](http://www.kidney.org/atoz/pdf/stayfit.pdf) with some basic information in there:

- Three main types of exercises are beneficial: stretching, strength, and aerobic
- If you are completely out of shape, start with stretching and basic strength until you can sustain an aerobic exercise.
- You should slow down if: the exercise feels very hard, you are out of breath when you try to talk, you feel your heart racing, or you are not fully recovered an hour after exercise.

Based on that information, heavy lifting and sprinting is not an option.  Probably some of the better options might include yoga or pilates.  Do keep a regular dialog with your doctor, as kidney issues are serious.  If they tell you to slow down, stop, or change what you are going, listen to them.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply..i am not out of shape totally..but started to get some fat around belly.So i like to be in shape.I jog daily..have no problem with that.but still is not enough i guess as fat is still there around belly.

Comment: Then take a look at what you are eating.  Make a food journal of everything that goes in your mouth.  It doesn't have to be complicated, just record what the food was and roughly how much you ate.  It can be quite eye opening.